# Cannot push changes in angular project using visual studio github

Tags: angular, visual-studio, github

I'm trying to use github extension on visual studio, every c# file works fine, but when I make changes inside the project ClientApp those changes are not detected. When I first pulled to my master branch my angular project had that .git folder which could have caused the problem, but now, I cant add those files anymore.

Bellow, my github branch. Notice that my ClientApp folder is diferrent.
[image]

How can I force my github to push my angular project to the main branch?

Answer (score 2):

If you want `ClientApp` content to be pushed alongside the rest of your project files, you would need to:

```
git rm --cached ClientApp    # no trailing /
git commit -m "Delete gitlink"
git add ClientApp
git commit -m "Add ClientApp content"
git push
```

Meaning: removing the nested `.git` folder inside `ClientApp` was not enough.
You need to delete the gitlink (special entry in the index) which recorded the root tree SHA1 of the nested repo `ClientApp`.